# How to pass a string in a javascript variable allowing every character

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, stringify

I need to pass some variables that are `Javascript objects`, something like this

```
var pageVars= [
    { origin:'page', property:'name', value:'whatever' },
    { origin:'session', property:'language', value:'whatever' },
];
```

Thing is that the value can come with **whatever character**, so I was trying to use

```
JSON.stringify('whatever')
```

But it won't do the work for example for

```
JSON.stringify('what'ever');
```

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean it's won't work with your example?  When I type in the exact same code that you have, I end up with the string ""what\"ever"" which is correct.

Comment: Sorry, @VtoCorleone, edited

Comment: 'what'ever' isn't a properly formatted JavaScript string.  You'd have to have 'what\'ever' for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you try using a for loop?

```
for (i in pageVars) {
passString+=i+":"+pageVars[i].toString()+";";
}
```